# How can proxy server inform browser to bypass that proxy and make direct connection?

Tags: http, proxy

I develop proxy server. It have an internal database of some hosts, with that browser should make direct connection, not through my proxy. Is there any way to inform browser that it should bypass proxy?

For example, I`ve found **305 Use Proxy** http header. Is it possible to make what I need with using that header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instruct browser using WPAD or PAC.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

It is browser responsibility to decide whenever use proxy or not.

Even large enterprises uses this technology, because it is transparent.